# Using FORFILES to delete Folders older than 2 days

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

here is what i'm trying to do:

**Use the forfiles Command in a .cmd script to delete folders from a specified path that are older than e. g. 2 days on a win7 machine.**

Edit: The Situation is the following under the path X:\backups are folders which contain daily backups e. g. 25.06.2014 next folder 24.06.2014 and so on.

My questions regarding this are now:

- /d in the help it always stresses --files--. So I'm not sure if this works for folders too.
- especially i'm not sure what it would do in combination with /s. So it would just run through the folders and delete the files - but what if already the parentfolder was too old? On a sidenote the whole concept of recursive is not clear to me and what it means i was not able to find out. It just means going through the folders right?
- If i would go with an IF-Statement then i would have to use 2 Variable @ISDIR and @FDATE. With this solution i don't know how to combine 2 If-Statements in the forfiles command and additionally i'm not sure if @FDATE is again only for files and not folders.

So how to do it right?

Reference of forfiles:
http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Greetings!

Comment: Is using PowerShell an option?

Answer (score 6):

## Solution

Despite its name, the `forfiles` command is able to handle both files *and* folders. Here's a batch script that does the job:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set target=X:\backups
set days=-2

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in (
`forfiles /p "%target%" /c "cmd /c if /i @isdir == true echo @path" /d %days% 2^>nul`
) do echo rd /s /q "%%~G"

pause
endlocal & exit /b
```

### How it works

First of all, the `target` and `days` variables are initialized. The first one is set to the folder you want to scan, and the latter is the amount of days. Negative values mean *older than or equal*.

The `forfiles` command is then run by specifying the folder and number of days that were set earlier. For each result, the special `@isdir` variable is checked: if the value is `true` the current entry is a folder, and its `@path` is echoed. The command output is then parsed to get all matching folders and delete them. For safety reasons, there's an extra `echo` command so you can check whether the right folders are removed.

When using the recursive switch (`/s`), all files, folders, and their subfolders are processed. In this case you don't want to; otherwise you might end up deleting old subfolders contained in newer folders, which shouldn't be touched at all.

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Comment: Thx for the answer but i'm having trouble to understand:

Comment: O.k. "Enter" leads to posting and "you are only allowed to edit for 5 minutes" so here is the actual post: Thx for the answer. Despite Googling i'm having trouble to understand: 1).. "usebackq delims=" %%G in.. - what does this line do? 2) What is the ` for? 3)It seems that you have an outside for loop in which the forfiles command runs. Isn't that what forfiles already does?

Comment: @user54512 The syntax is `for /f "<options>" <variable> in (<input>) do <whatever>`. The `usebackq` option enables the use of quotes for paths/file names (quotes are used to denote strings otherwise), and backticks for commands. The default delimiters are space chars and tabs; `delims=` clears them, to avoid breaking paths containing spaces. In this specific case you could just use this: `forfiles /p "X:\backups" /c "cmd /c if /i @isdir == true echo rd /s /q @path" /d -2` By wrapping it in an extra `for` loop you get a more flexible solution should you need to run more than a single command.

Comment: Note that TRUE and FALSE values must be UPPERCASE in some Windows versions, including my copies of Windows 7 and 2008 R2.

Comment: Excellent answer, exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

The one-line PowerShell doesn't quite get you there. It does not include the full path to the list of files. Also, you may need to recurse. This works:

---

get-childitem "D:\backup" |? {$*.psiscontainer -and $*.lastwritetime -le (get-date).adddays(-0)} |% {remove-item
 D:\backup\$_ -force -recurse -whatif}

---

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line PowerShell approach:

```
get-childitem "x:\backups" |? {$_.psiscontainer -and $_.lastwritetime -le (get-date).adddays(-2)} |% {remove-item $_ -force -whatif}
```

You can adjust the age threshold through the adddays' parameter. This is still in "WhatIf" mode, so you can test it first and see what would happen. Remove the -whatif to make it actually delete the folders.

Source: [TechNet Forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ab5f85e8-88f2-4de3-8d8d-eeb083e18aab/remove-folders-older-than-two-weeks-old)

Comment: Thanks but using Powershell is not possible. I would need it in a .bat or .cmd file

Answer (score 0):

how it should work on WIndows server 2019?
I think " `" have problem on new OS

```
@echo off
setlocal

set target=X:\backups
set days=-2

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in (
`forfiles /p "%target%" /c "cmd /c if /i @isdir == true echo @path" /d %days% 2^>nul`
) do echo rd /s /q "%%~G"

pause
endlocal & exit /b
```